# GUI button with AceFEM functions

Tags: gui-construction, finite-element-method, button, acegen

I would like to have a GUI with a button that starts AceFEM analysis and then some results appear. I have taken one example from the documentation on boundary condition specification and I wrapped it into a function. It works and returns graphics of the deformed mesh

```
<< AceFEM`

buttonContent[load_?NumberQ] := Module[{H = 50, A = 100, B = 75},
  SMTInputData[];
  SMTAddDomain["A","OL:SED3H1DFHYH1NeoHooke", {"E *" -> 1000., "ν *" -> .49}];
  SMTAddMesh[
   Hexahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {A, 0, 0}, {A, B, 0}, {0, B, 0}, {0, 0, H}, {A, 0, H}, {A, B, H}, {0, B, H}}], 
   "A", "H1", {20, 15, 10}
   ];
  SMTAddEssentialBoundary[
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, B, 0}, {0, B, H}, {0, 0, H}}],
   1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0
   ];
  SMTAddNaturalBoundary[
   Polygon[{{0, B/2, H}, {A/2, B/2, H}, {A/2, B, H}, {0, B, H}}],
   3 -> Polygon[{load}]
   ];
  SMTAnalysis[];

  Do[
   SMTNextStep["Δλ" -> 0.1];
   While[SMTConvergence[10^-8, 12], SMTNewtonIteration[];];,
   {i, 1, 10}];
  SMTShowMesh["DeformedMesh"->True,"BoundaryConditions"->True,"Field"->"u"]
 ]

buttonContent[-100]
```

[image]

When I use this function as the `Button` action it seems that analysis is initialized, but there are no results. Why is this happening? Is not possible to use AceFEM functions in `Dynamic` expressions and other GUI elements?

```
Column[{
  InputField[Dynamic[load], Number, FieldSize -> 8],
  Row[{"Load= ", Dynamic[load]}],
  Row[{
    Button["Calculate", gr = buttonContent[load]],
    Button["Clear", gr = ""]
    }],
  Dynamic[gr]
  }, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: How long does it take to compute? If you don't supply the `Method->"Queued"` option to `Button` it aborts after ~6 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Solution to the problem is to use `Button[...,Method->"Queued"]`. Quoting the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html) for `Button`

> "By default, button functions are evaluated on a preemptive link and time out after 5 seconds:"
>
> "Use Method->"Queued" to evaluate button functions on the main link, which never times out:"

Your analysis function was evaluated on the preemptive link by default and since it seems to take more than 5 seconds to evaluate, the link timed out.

```
buttonContent[-100]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{8.78588, Null}*)
```

I think that all AceFEM analyses should be evaluated through the main link, because typically they are time consuming or unpredictable time-wise (e.g. using adaptive time step). See this [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#681967067) for more information on synchronous and asynchronous evaluation. I have also wrapped your example in `DynamicModule` to encapsulate local variables and prevent unwanted interaction of multiple GUIs.

```
DynamicModule[{load = -100, gr = ""},
 Column[{
   InputField[Dynamic[load], Number, FieldSize -> 8],
   Row[{"Load= ", Dynamic[load]}],
   Row[{
     Button["Calculate",
      gr = buttonContent[load],
      Method -> "Queued"
      ],
     Button["Clear", gr = ""]
     }],
   Dynamic[gr]
   }, Frame -> True]
 ]
```

[image: gui]